# How to merge data into one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

This is my query

```
 select t.tourID,s.studentID,s.studentDOB,s.studentAddress,ta.teacherName 
 from Student s 
 join Tour_studentlist ts on s.studentID=ts.studentID
 join Tour_teacherlist tt on tt.tourID = ts.tourID
 join Tour t on t.tourID =ts.tourID
 join Coach c on c.coachID = t.coachID
 join Teacher ta on ta.teacherID=tt.teacherID
 where ts.tourID=ts.tourID
 GROUP BY t.tourID , s.studentID,s.studentDOB,s.studentAddress,ta.teacherName ;
```

Output Table:  [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHYLv.png)

how to merge teacher name data into 1?
Eg.

```
TourID|studentID|studentDOb|studentAddress|teacherName
1     |1        |1999-01-10|No.15....     |Jessica,Lucy,Victoria|
```

Comment: It probably prints twice because there's both a text/plain and a text/html in the test message you're using; multipart/alternative means just that, alternative. You'll need to add handling of some more mime types and save/prompt if appropriate. Have a look at getContentDisposition(), and remember that a multipart can contain another multipart.

Comment: You're after a crosstab. Please do some research on crosstabs, try some code and post it with any specific problems.